# How to end a loop early if a user says to C++

Tags: c++

Note: This is a  homework assignment.

I am trying to make a program that plays the game Pig! Pig is a game with the following rules:

`1. First to get 100 GAME POINTS is the victor.
 2. On your turn, you roll a dice. If you get a 1 at any roll, you end your turn and add 0 to your GAME SCORE.
 3. If you roll any value other than a 1, you have the option to HOLD or PLAY. If you PLAY, your roll is added to your TURN SCORE and you roll again. If you HOLD, your TURN SCORE is added to your GAME SCORE and the turn passes to the computer.`

The game is coming along very easily until I get to the following problem (see code):

```
int player(){
    char PlayAgain = 'Y';
    int turn_score = 0;
    while (PlayAgain != 'N' || PlayAgain != 'n'){
        int dice;

        srand(time(NULL));
        dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
        turn_score = turn_score + dice;

        if (dice != 1){
            cout << "You rolled a " << dice << "! Would you like to roll again? [Y/N]: ";
            cin >> PlayAgain;
            if (PlayAgain == 'N' || PlayAgain == 'n'){
                /*END TURN AND return turn_score;*/
            }
        }
        if (dice == 1){
            cout << endl << "Oops! You rolled a 1! Your turn is ended, and you add nothing to your score.\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            /*END TURN, NO SCORE ADDED*/
        }
    }
}
```

How can I have the program end the loop prematurely (if either the play HOLDS or dice == 1) and return the proper value (if HOLD, return turn_score. Else return 0)? [See two noted sections]

Comment: Use a `break` statement when the condition is met.

Comment: @Zaphod That wouldn't allow me to return a value depending on the situation in the `while`, would it? If not, then a break doesn't achieve that I need.

Comment: Try harder by yourself :-)

Comment: @Ryan_W4588 - `break` will get you out of the loop, not the function, you can return after the loop.

Comment: @ddriver I understand what a break does, but how can I let the program figure out that a 1 was rolled on a dice, for instance, if `dice` is a local variable within the loop

Comment: @Ryan_W4588 - move `dice` outside the loop

Comment: @Ryan_W4588. If the condition is met you can either `break` from the loop and `return` what you need to return outside the loop or you can directly `return` when the condition is met, instead of using the `break`.

Comment: I just realized you have a function that should return an int that returns nothing. Doesn't the compiler like complain or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` to get out of a loop. Since you're saying that you want to return "the right value" then you should do something like that:

On the first if clause

```
if (PlayAgain == 'N' || PlayAgain == 'n'){
            /**Game-Specific logic here**/
            return turn_score
        }
```

and on the second one:

```
if (dice == 1){
        cout << endl << "Oops! You rolled a 1! Your turn is ended, and you add nothing to your score.\n";
        /**Game-Specific logic here**/
        cin.get();
        return turn_score;
    }
```

A return statement doesn't need to be at the end of the function and more than one return statements can co-exist inside the same function

Comment: This makes sense, I suppose I thought that a `return` couldn't be within a loop. So, does a `return` instantly end a function?

Comment: Yes it does. But keep in mind that you can also stop loops with break. Sometimes you want to end a loop without ending the function

Answer (score 0):

Rather then correcting your code I would like to make you clear about what actually is needed here.

---

Ever heard of `break;` statement.Let us understand with a simple example
see the following code snippet where your program is taking input from the user,it keeps on taking input from the user until you press 'A'

```
char var;
while(true)
{
cin>>var;
if(var=='A') break;
}
```

Now in this program,the while loop is set to `true` and will keep on running and taking input from the user,and the if statement will not run until the user have entered 'A'. AND the moment 'A' is given as the input,`break` will take the control out of the `while` loop for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about having your 'return' statement (with the proper value depending on the case) inside your loop? This will break both the loop and the function, but returning the value you needed.